# How to reference ember.js controllers that are in nested folders?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm building an `EventController` that has little modules of logic within sections or `div`'s of the event screen.

Say for instance, event details may be in the main Event template but a small section might be the user's status with the event such as whether they RSVP'd etc. but since it's controlled by a different model than the event I'd think it should have it's own controller.

Would I put this in the EventController like such:

```
Controller = BaseController.extend
  needs: ['event/user-status-area']
  userStatusArea: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.event.user-status-area")
```

This obviously isn't working otherwise I wouldn't be here... but I'm looking for suggestions.

I'm very new to ember / ember-cli concepts so I'm sorry if I'm just blatantly way off base here.

In my brain, I would imagine keeping everything about an event centralized under the one EventController...

Am I missing something big?  Is this possibly where the "Router" comes in?

**UPDATE:**
If so, I'd imagine it might look something like this in Router:

```
Route = BaseRoute.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('event',params.id)
  renderTemplate: (controller,model) ->
    userStatusController = controller.get('userStatusArea')

    @render 'event'

    @render 'event/user-status-area',
      into: 'event',
      outlet: 'user-status-area',
      controller:userStatusController
      model: model.event_user.find(@get('session.current_user.userId'))
```

No idea if this would even be considered a best practice for ember?
I guess this would be the question... what is the best way to create this type of structure?

Comment: I can't remember exactly how it's renamed, but there is a way to get access. I suggest setting a breakpoint and inspecting the `controllers` property. I think it ends up being something like `controllers.evnetUserStatusArea`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a nested route:

router.js

```
this.resource('event',{path:'event/:id'}, function(){
  this.route('userStatus');
})
```

in the event template, you would add an {{outlet}}

When you transition to event/{id}/userStatus, the outlet would be automatically rendered with the templates/event/user-status.hbs template.

When you reference controllers/views etc. in ember-cli with a filename e.g. user-status, you need to reference it in camelCase:

```
needs: ['event/userStatus'],
```

not user-status.

Hope this helps.